# How to output class as nested dictionary with attributes calculated if other attributes are != None

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to have a class that has multiple attributes. I'd like for it to also have a way to output those attributes as dictionary and skip over all the None values. Also in a perfect scenario I'd like this dict to be nested but first things first:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a=False, b=None, c=None, ...):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        ...

    @property
        def dictionary(self):
            dictionary = { k:v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if v != None }
        return dictionary
```

This works fine however the problem is when trying to include result from self.a + self.b if != None in the dictionary. The `__dict__` only outputs values that are a part of `__init__`. I tried to solve this by using additional attribute and then using setter:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a=False, b=None, c=None, ... , _var=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        ...
        self.var = None

    @property
    def _var(self):
        _var = None
        return self.var

    @_var.setter
    def _var(self):
        if self.a & self.b != None:
            self.var = self.a + self.b
            return self.var

    @property
        def dictionary(self):
            dictionary = { k:v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if v != None }
        return dictionary
```

Unfortunately this doesn't initialize when I create the instance.. Can it even be done? I think I'm looking wrong way but somehow `__dict__` seems to be the right way to do this. I'm very new to OOP so this is all very new to me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where did `self.price` and `self.size` come from? Did you mean to write `if self.a is not None and self.b is not None:`?

Comment: The setter is only used if you write `self._var = ...`; it doesn't really make sense for it to return a value.

Comment: Swap your use of `var` and `_var`. `var` is the name of the publicly acessible property; `_var` is the private attribute (if any) that backs it.

Comment: sorry about that typo - copy pasting and didn't see that - meant self.a + self.b

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a need for the setter; just put your condition in the getter itself:

```
@property
def var(self):
    if self.a is not None and self.b is not None:
        return self.a + self.b
```

Comment: I've updated the second code block because there probably was a confusion. However this solution throws an error 'AttributeError: can't set attribute'. If I remove var from `__init__` it compiles but doesn't output the value in dictionary (using `__dict__`)